# Linking Events of deployed smart contract to a webhook

Tags: webhooks, ethereum, solidity

I am trying to listen to events that come from the smart contract(solidity-ethereum), by using webhooks.
Can anyone guide me on this?

Comment: I need answer to this question too.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution would be to use QuikNode webhook APIs:

https://blog.quiknode.io/introducing-webhooks-for-ethereum/